# Zentyal server + RSAT: create an administrator limited to a specific group of PCs

Tags: windows, administrator, accounting

In my configuration I have a Zentyal 6 server that act as a PDC and 90 Windows client .

I need to create a doman admin account that has right only to a specific group of PCs.

Is it possibile to create this kind of account using RSAT tools? Or there Is another way It do this?

I have tried with "users and groups" tool of RSAT with no result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A domain admin account and local administrator account on a computer are two entirely different objects. The only reason why a domain admin account has administrative privileges on a local computer is because the `Domain Admins` group is in the local `Administrators` group.

If you create a domain admin, that is exactly what they are. A domain admin with access to far more than what it sounds like you want to provide.

What you are trying to provide is a local administrator on a subset of PCs.

1. Create a regular domain user
2. Create a domain group to put administrators of these PCs in.
3. Put the new domain user in the new domain group you created.
4. Create a new group policy preference to add the new group to a PC’s local `Administrators` group.
5. Apply and filter your group policy for that subset of PCs using a new OU, WMI filtering, or ACLs on the group policy.